# Simple design for routing data between multiple objects?

Tags: oop, publish-subscribe, observer-pattern

In my current design I use several classes which each represents some
peripheral device. Each class provide both methods for input as well as
callbacks for output. Some output from one class shall be used as input
to another class, so a simple design is to let the client implement all
callbacks and handle all routing between objects.

This can be illustrated with the following simplified example. In my 
application the number of classes and inputs and outputs are higher.

```
interface CentralLockControlCb
{
  void onCentralLockStateChanged(bool on);
}

class CentralLockControl
{
  void setDoorLockedIndicator(bool locked);
}

interface DoorControlCb
{
  void onDoorLockedStateChanged(bool locked);
}

class DoorControl
{
  void setCentralLockState(bool on);
}

class Main : public CentralLockControlCb, DoorControlCb
{
  private CentralLockControl centrallock;
  private DoorControl door;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    clc = new CentralLockControl(this);
    dc = new DoorControl(this);
  }

  void onCentralLockStateChanged(bool on)
  {
    door.setCentralLockState(on);
  }

  void onDoorLockedStateChanged(bool locked)
  {
    centrallock.setDoorLockedIndicator(locked);
  }  
}
```

The solution above avoids that the classes need to know about each other,
but on the other hand, they now seem very coupled to the Main class.

As an alternative, I considered letting each class allow multiple observers,
and letting the classes observe each other. As another alternative I considered 
something similar to a publisher/subscriber pattern, but it seems

What design would you recommend for such a problem?

Comment: What does `public static void main(String[] args)` it do with C++ ?
(wrong tag?)

Comment: Publisher - Subscriber and Observer are the same thing.

Comment: The solution above won't work anyway, since you cannot assign a pointer to an object. This looks much more like Java code, but then again it isn't valid Java either. So please decide for a language first. Or, since it seems to be a more general OO problem, declare it as pseudo-code right away. In this case just remove the C++ tag.

Comment: You are right, I should not have assigned the C++ tag. This shall be considered as a general OO problem. I am new to this site.

Comment: Ummm, is that multiple inheritence that I see there?

Comment: @tcarvin, the CentralLockControlCb and DoorControlCb are interfaces. I will correct the example, thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) that you could use instead of Main being used in that capacity. 
Once you go that route, you'd be able to register your devices to listen to specific events about other devices in a very nice way. Moreover, this design will likely lead you towards generalizing your events to carry useful state so that your devices can ignore certain events when needed. It will keep your Event Aggregator less complex (there will be no decisions as to who needs to be called when an event happens).
Finally, you would be able to notify interested parties asynchronously, which may or may to be important in your case.